# Python strptime() not formatting correctly

Tags: python-3.x, string, datetime, strptime

When I try to convert a string to a datetime it is giving me an unexpected return value.

I am on OS X running Python 3.7.3

Code that I have:

```
import datetime

# I have confirmed the value of this var to be {str} '01/01/2020'
effective_date = request_body.get('effective_date', None) 
effective_date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(effective_date, "%m/%d/%Y") # returns '2020-01-01 00:00:00'
```

When I run this code in my application I get:

```
ValueError: time data '2020-01-01T00:00:00' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'
```

Comment: Can you try to run `effective_date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('01/01/2020', "%m/%d/%Y")`. This just replaces the variable with what you're saying it is equal to. Does it still fail? I ran your code provided and it worked as expected.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the code `datetime.datetime.strptime(effective_date, "%m/%d/%Y")` assuming `effective_date` is `'01/01/2020'` . When are you getting this error and where ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for but I think this might help

```
effective_date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(effective_date, "%m/%d/%Y").date() # returns '2020-01-01'

print(effective_date1.strftime("%x")) # now prints 01/01/20
```